# box shadow on highlighted row

Tags: css

I'm trying to add a box shadow to a row that when hovered has a highlight color. I want the box shadow, along with the highlight color, to only show when hovered. The row is divided into Main, threads, posts, etc. I can apply the effect to the individual components but can't for the life of me figure out how to do it to the row as a whole. I use Chrome but would need the code to be supported by most browsers.

Thank you so much for any help.

Answer (score 1):

A table row ([`<tr>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr)) element has a special innate display property ([`display:table-row`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)) which helps to create the structure of a table. The nature of this display type prevents many types of styling, because it is considered a "structural" tag rather than a "display" tag.

You can overwrite the display type and then set display properties as desired. Be aware that overwriting the display type may have unintended side-effects in the look of your table, but these can usually be mitigated by styling it to look as it previously did (changing margins, paddings, etc.).

I've included an example below which changes the display type to "block", then applies a highlight and box-shadow to each row when hovering. This should work in any browser which supports box-shadow ([here are the major ones](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow)).

```css
tr {
    display: block;
}
tr:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    background-color: #F8DE7E;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td> <td>b</td> <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td> <td>2</td> <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td> <td>b</td> <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td> <td>2</td> <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry to be a bit dense but where would the <table> code go? I'm new at coding so . . . Thanks

Comment: @ForeverSunshine when you said "row" in your question, i assumed that you were talking about a table row. if you aren't already using a table, then this solution might not be the best option. please update your question to include some code snippets (especially the HTML structure) that illustrate the problem you are having. be sure to clearly explain what you've tried and how the results are differing from your expectations.

Comment: I apologize for not being more clear. I am talking about a row in a table. I have done some more fiddling with it and have it working exactly how I wanted it. Thank you so much for all your help! Others told me it was not possible but you managed to provide the help and it's perfect! What you gave did exactly what my mind pictured it should.

Comment: @ForeverSunshine if this answer is a suitable solution to the problem presented in your question, please take a moment to click the green checkmark next to my answer so the question is marked resolved and other people might be able to find this answer as well.